# Setting MAILTO="" for cron in Ubuntu

Tags: cron

I have tried setting MAILTO="" under `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/default/cron`, but I still receive mail notifications from cron. Is there a single place to disable all mail from cron, as opposed to per-task output redirection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `sudo crontab -e` on terminal. At the top of the file set `MAILTO=""`

This should help you to disable email.

If need you can restart the cron using command `/etc/init.d/crond restart`

Comment: Well now I'm embarrassed. Having read many similar answers I tried going "under the hood" too much for my own good... Thanks a lot!

Comment: `crond` doesn't exist in my 14.04.4 but  `sudo /etc/init.d/crond restart` works.

Comment: what if you want to do this globally? on ubuntu 18.04?